# Proper way to publish a website running on service fabric?

Tags: azure, reverse-proxy, azure-service-fabric

After look at serveral videos and the official documentation I am still confused as to how one publishes a website running on Azure Service Fabric.

I see that there are multiple ways of doing this:
- Running the app on all nodes and having the website listen on port 80.
- Using some sort of Reverse Proxy in front of the cluster and the SF Reverse Proxy
- Writing a webapp that connects to SF and acts as a Reverse Proxy.

Looking around it seems to me that there are some reservations against opening up the SF Reverse Proxy outside of the cluster, so what I'm wondering is if the following setup has any flaws/problems. Are there better ways for doing this?

1. Installing IIS on all SF nodes
2. Setup IIS to act as a reverse proxy for SF pointing ie. cust.domain.com to the proper application using the SF Reverse Proxy.
3. Simply having the cust.domain.com point at the public IP of the load balancer.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would install IIS in a service fabric cluster. I would either use ASP.net core with self hosting or use app services. I'm not sure what your use case for using Service Fabric is.

Comment: SF can't run alongside IIS. Says so in the documentation.

Comment: Reservations about using SF reverse proxy as an edge proxy are unfounded. It uses same codebase as http.sys so it's fine.

Comment: I'm not talking about installing IIS inside of the SF cluster, rather on the same server.  

Where does it say that it can't run on the same server as IIS? I've got them running on the same server for a local SF cluster seemingly living happily together.